# Display output on the form in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing

I'm designing a windows form. I have output to be displayed on the form it self.
Tried using print, but it is not working.
How do I do that?

I'M NOT PRINTING THE FORM.

ADDED:
I need to display 3 numbers with text string next to each number.
I want to do this in a way that it shows in the form or label in the form without overwriting the previous results.

example:

```
    3 (wrong) 1 (right) 8 (wrong)
    2 (wrong) 1 (right) 5 (right)
    9 (right) 1 (right) 5 (right)
```

ADDED:
Thanks for the help everyone. one more question and i think i'm good.

I was thinking of doing something like this inside a loop, problem is I can't add a string and an int together to make a new var:
        Xnum1 = Xnum1 + 50

```
    Xnum2 = Xnum1 + ".0F"

    Ynum1 = Ynum1 + 50

    Ynum2 = Ynum1 + ".0F"
```

Comment: Is it VB.NET or VB6? They have almost nothing in common except the name.

Comment: WHY? Whats wrong with lables and panels etc? Anyway, if you must you can overide the forms paint event

Comment: I don't get the problem (" I have output to be displayed on the form it self")

Comment: I'm using visual basic 2010 express. I come from a vb6 programming bg. i have no idea what the diff is.

Comment: vb.net is really a whole new language. A **lot** of the paradigms you learned with vb6 need to be thrown out the window... even some of the things that still seem to work may have the opposite of the intended effect in subtle ways.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Not that printing data directly to the form like that was a good idea in VB6 either :)

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 you could use the `Print` statement to draw to the surface of the form.  In VB.NET, however, you should be using the  `Form.CreateGraphics` method to create a new `Graphics` object that can be used to draw to the form's surface.  For instance:

```
Private Sub PrintText(text As String, x As Single, y As Single)
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    g.DrawString(text, New Font("Arial", 16), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), New PointF(x, y))
End Sub
```

That would be the closest equivalent to using the VB6 `Print` statement like that.

However, I would strongly recommend using a control to display the data.  It looks like for the data you need to display, a simple multi-line text box or label would be sufficient.  For instance:

```
Private Sub AppendResult(index As Integer, right As Boolean)
    If right Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & " " & index.ToString() & " (right)"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & " " & index.ToString() & " (wrong)"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to get more fancy, you could look into using a data grid, a list box, a list view, or even a table layout control instead.

Comment: You wouldn't print new lines, you'd just print at a greater Y coordinate.

Comment: I see thanks alot. I see the difference now. I will keep playing it =)

Comment: Is there a way to update the Y component of the       New PointF(50.0F, 50.0F))   , via a variable. this way i can use the same print statement in a loop and just update the y value

Comment: Yes.  I updated my answer to show an example.  But I beg you.  Please don't do it this way :(

Comment: Thanks, it does seem like a messy way to do it. But I'm only doing this twice in my program/game

Comment: It is not working the way i intended. It was way easier to print to form in vb6. I have to look into a diff way to do it.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: I like your idea for a multiline textbox .So simple and the job is do-able.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most efficient way is to use a [tableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) with 6 columns. Add in each cell a label showing in the first cell the number, in the second the indicator for that number (right/wrong). Do the same for second and third number.(second number = third and fourth cell, third number =fifth and sixth cell)

For the next set of numbers you can add a new row with with labels in each cell.

I'll add some code to make my answer more professional.

First you add the tableLayoutPanel in your form. You size it as you like (make its width, long enough to handle the data)
You delete the lastRow and then you add columns (you want to have 6 columns). You edit the size of the columns to be Percentage =16.67%

```
Public Class Form1

Private rowIndex
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For i = 0 To 4 Step 2
        Dim val As Integer = 3
        AddLabels(val, i, 0)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 5 Step 2
        Dim val As String = "right"
        AddLabels(val, i, 0)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1


    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30))
    Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Height = Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Height + 30
    For i = 0 To 4 Step 2
        Dim val As Integer = 3 'here you have to put your number
        AddLabels(val, i, rowIndex)
    Next
    For i = 1 To 5 Step 2
        Dim val As String = "right" 'here you have to put your indicator
        AddLabels(val, i, rowIndex)
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub AddLabels(ByVal lblValue As String, ByVal column As Integer, ByVal row As Integer)
    Dim lblHeader As New Label
    lblHeader.AutoSize = True
    lblHeader.Margin = New Padding(0)
    lblHeader.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    lblHeader.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    lblHeader.Dock = DockStyle.None
    lblHeader.Text = lblValue

    'Put the lblHeader in the right cell
    Dim lblHeaderPos As New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(column, row)
    TableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(lblHeader, lblHeaderPos)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblHeader)

End Sub
```

Let me know if you facing any problems.

Also if you don't know how many rows you will add, put the tableLyoutPanel inside a panel. Make the panel's property AutoScroll=True and then you can add infinite number of new rows.